# Is it possible to reference InputActionAsset controls, even when inactive, for use in MonoBehavior Update methods?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This current project has 3rd party controllers/cameras that I am converting over to the new Input system 1.0.1. I'd like to keep its functionality within the old controllers but gain the benefit of being able to switch action maps and such. Most of the controller code does their work in MonoBehavior Update.

I am currently struggling to find a solution to converting these:

```
if (Input.GetButton())
if (Input.GetButtonDown())
if (Input.GetButtonUp())
```

I have been referencing the migration documentation to try and find a solution found here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Migration.html , but I seem to be misunderstanding or missing something with the conversion for these specific controls.

For the button controls, they state that one should use the `ButtonControl` props, but I am not sure the proper way to get a hold on these controls. Here is an example of what I tried, at the top of the 3rd party controller Update, that was most promising:

```
var fire1Btn = _inputManager.PlayerInputs.Player.Fire1.activeControl as ButtonControl;
```

*`_inputManager` is a MonoBehavior object that stores my ref to the `PlayerInputs` object which is my `: IInputActionCollection, IDisposable` class which has the `InputActionAsset`, this is the .cs file generated automatically from the .inputactions file by Unity.

Then in the 3rd party controller code I replace the respective `GetButtonDown` `GetButton` `GetButtonUp` with this:

```
if (fire1Btn != null && fire1Btn.wasPressedThisFrame)
if (fire1Btn != null && fire1Btn.isPressed)
if (fire1Btn != null && fire1Btn.wasReleasedThisFrame)
```

This causes some issues though. `.activeControl` is null when actions are not firing and I don't think this behaves in the same way as the legacy controls. For example, when I go into the scene and start moving the player controller around, press forward, then release, the character continues to run forward, as if the value coming in from that control did not go back to 0 before the activeControl was nulled out again. There is also a `.controls[]` array on the object but this has a long list of controls that I could not easily distinguish which, if any, were the correct control.

*edit1: after testing it appears as though `wasReleasedThisFrame` on an `activeControl` is never true, which I guess makes sense if this control object is only ever active when its being used.

Is there a proper way to get a hold on these controls? Is this approach naive in some way? Any help or documentation on what to do here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I resolved some of the held movement issues as problems with the null conditionals in the controller. Almost have this working with the activeControl now but the checking for null conditionals is still tricky in some spots and still having issues with certain key combo that get held.

Would really love to know if there is a way to have access to a non-null bound control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my reading, tests, and responses from various individuals, I am going to tentatively assume the answer to my original question is:

**No, you cannot tap into an input control when its not active**

**Update 12/8/2020**
Based on more recent findings I found that `.activeControl` will run into issues on composites and I found a better way to tackle this issue. `.wasReleasedThisFrame` continues to be troublesome though. This newer solution uses an extension method to check press states, with only released state requiring some kind of tracking on previous frame state of a button. Here are the better ways to check state, though the wasReleasedThisFrame method did not work correctly:

```
inputAction.ReadValue<float>() > 0f; // for isPressed state
inputAction.triggered && inputAction.ReadValue<float>() > 0f; // for wasPressedThisFrame
inputAction.triggered && inputAction.ReadValue<float>() == 0f; // for wasReleasedThisFrame ** Does not function properly **
```

As for `.wasReleasedThisFrame` you'll have to implement some kind of tracking of previous frame similar to the one I did below. I ended up using a dictionary on my input manager class to track the states, then passed it into the static extension method on checks.

```
public static bool WasReleasedThisFrame(this InputAction inputAction, Dictionary<string, ButtonControlMask> maskStates)
{
    return maskStates.ContainsKey(inputAction.name) && maskStates[inputAction.name].wasReleasedThisFrame;
}
```

Bear in mind that if you check these values in some other mono-behavior update method (like how I do mine in my manager class), you could run into ScriptOrder issues unless you are checking the values in `LateUpdate()` like I am.

I'm still on the hunting for a better solution for the `.wasReleasedThisFrame` problem.

**This is the my previous solution**: Based on my original code from the question and specifically assuming you have the correct entries in your InputActionAsset, generated or created the c# input class from the asset file, instantiated the input class, and have reference to it, something like this should work:

```
public class ButtonControlMask
{
    public bool wasPressedThisFrame { get; set; }
    public bool isPressed { get; set; }
    public bool wasReleasedThisFrame { get; set; }
}

private bool _fire1BtnWasActiveLastFrame = false;

private void LateUpdate() // works in Update as well
{
    // set our controls
    dynamic fire1Btn = _inputManager.PlayerInputs.Player.Fire1.activeControl as ButtonControl;
    if (fire1Btn == null)
    {
        // never let our control be null, use mask and dynamics to prevent having to check for null
        fire1Btn = new ButtonControlMask()
        {
            // _fire1BtnWasActiveLastFrame will check out last frames state
            wasPressedThisFrame = false, 
            isPressed = false, 
            wasReleasedThisFrame = _fire1BtnWasActiveLastFrame
        };

        // if it was active, and is null now, we can now reset our flag
        if (_fire1BtnWasActiveLastFrame) _fire1BtnWasActiveLastFrame = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // we have an active control, set our active last frame flag
        _fire1BtnWasActiveLastFrame = true;
    }

    // migrated code below ---
    if (fire1Btn.wasPressedThisFrame)  // This replaces Input.GetButtonDown()
    if (fire1Btn.isPressed) // This replaces Input.GetButton()
    if (fire1Btn.wasReleasedThisFrame) // This replaces Input.GetButtonUp()
}
```

Just using the `.activeControl` we have values for our `.wasPressedThisFrame` and `.isPressed`, however, `.wasReleasedThisFrame` is unknown to us as the control goes null the instant its not being used. To go around this we store the previous frames state in the `_fire1BtnWasActiveLastFrame` variable based on if the control was null or not. Then in the next frame, if the control is null, `_fire1BtnWasActiveLastFrame` will inform us that `.wasReleasedThisFrame` should be true on our masked class for ButtonControl only for this frame.

It's not pretty but this should allow for clean migration of `Input.GetButtonDown` `Input.GetButton` `Input.GetButtonUp` within your legacy code without having to change or check logic.